# Terminate function a() when function b() failed

Tags: php, curl

We are a little bit confuse how we can achieve this problem. We don't want to run the createsite function in our code if createSubaccount function fails. We would truly appreciate any feedbacks, comments, guides on our code.

```
<?php
//Set API user and password
define("API_USER","user");
define("API_PASS","pw");

    $createdSite = createSite($_REQUEST['template_id'],$_REQUEST['original_url']);
    //echo 'Site Created: ' . $createdSite . '<br/>';
    $accountCreated = createSubAccount($_REQUEST['email']);//client email
    //echo 'Account created: ' . $accountCreated . '<br/>';


    $first_name = $_REQUEST['first_name'];//First Name
    $last_name = $_REQUEST['last_name'];//Last Name

    $retArr = ["sso"=>$sso_link,"ru"=>$resetURL,"ac"=>$accountCreated,"fn"=>$first_name,"ln"=>$last_name];//assoc array

    print json_encode ($retArr);//json string


function createSite($template_id,$original_url) {
    //create array with data
    if($original_url) {
        $data = array("template_id"=>$_REQUEST['template_id'],"url"=>$original_url);    
    } else {
        $data = array("template_id"=>$_REQUEST['template_id']);
    }
    //turn data into json to pass via cURL
    $data = json_encode($data);
    //Set cURL parameters
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.website.com/api/create');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, API_USER.':'.API_PASS);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    //execute cURL call and get template data
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    //check for errors in cURL
    if(curl_errno($ch)) {
        die('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    $output = json_decode($output);
    return $output->site_name;//Output /Return :  {"site_name":"28e1182c"}
}

function createSubAccount($emailToCreate) {
    $first_name = $_REQUEST['first_name'];//First Name
    $last_name = $_REQUEST['last_name'];//Last Name
    $data = '{"account_name":"'.$emailToCreate.'", "first_name":"'.$first_name.'", "last_name":"'.$last_name.'"}';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.website.com/api/create');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, API_USER.':'.API_PASS);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    //execute cURL call and get template data
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) == 204) {
        curl_close($ch);
        return $emailToCreate;//Expected return HTTP Code: 204 No Content
    } else {
        curl_close($ch);
        $output = 'failed';
        return $output;
        die('Account creation failed, error: '. $output . '<br/>');
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: This might be better for [codereview.stackoverflow.com](http://codereview.stackoverflow.com) ...

Answer (score 0):

This is where an `Exception` comes in handy.

```
function createSite() {
     throw new \Exception('Failed');
}

try {
    $createdSite = createSite($_REQUEST['template_id'],$_REQUEST['original_url']);
    //echo 'Site Created: ' . $createdSite . '<br/>';
    $accountCreated = createSubAccount($_REQUEST['email']);//client email
} catch(\Exception $err) {
     echo $err->getMessage();
}
```

The `Exception` prevents the rest of the code in the block from executing once thrown.